# dynamic spaces between divs

Tags: html, css

So i got a Div that its width is set on 100% width so that means it can be every size. how ever that div has the value " min-width:950px " so its width size cant go under 950.

inside that div i have 2 lines , every line contain 4 div - with specific value of width

now whats happen is when someone with low resolution enter my site he can see the 4 divs getting together just fine :

[image]

but when someone with hugh resolution enter my site its like this:

[image]

what im looking to do is when someone with high resolution enter my site the 4 divs will take same spaces from each other , so it will be look like that:

[image]

how can i do that? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Styling

```
#container {
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 950px;
  border: solid 1px Black; // Change this
}

#container div {
  width: 100px; //Change this
  display: inline-block;
  background: red; // Change this
}

#container:after {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

### HTML Elements

```
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Codepen (Sandbox): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HdtiC

Original Article: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

Comment: hey i just came back home sorry for the long delay.. anyway , thats just great but i dont get one thing , when you add text to one of the four boxs that box getting messed up , though if all the four boxs is havinf texts its alright , take a look at that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kjgno , how can you explain it?

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work as shown above.  The original article (linked) actually does, however.  The difference is the original article uses fixed heights..  the code shown above does not, and it does not work properly.